# What is going on in these five different ways of declaring a cString?

Tags: c++, c, string, char

An explanation in another question (one I cannot find now) is that "string" and {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'} are equivalent.  In fact, the first four declarations below all compile and seem to do the same thing.  But then why doesn't the fifth declaration compile? It seems that they are not equivalent after all.  So my question is what exactly is going on in the four correct and the one incorrect cstring declaration?

```
int main()
{
    char cString1[]="string";

    char * cString2 = "string";

    char cString3[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g', '\0'};

    char cString4[7] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};

    char * cString5 = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are doing strings C-style. Any reason to tag the question as C++?

Comment: I'm reading a C++ tutorial and learning C++.  I know this is a c-style String, but I do not know if it matters that I'm compiling as a C++ program.

Comment: @KerrekSB No it does not compile -- the fifth one is a problem.

Comment: BTW, the standard explicitly says that initializing a char* from a string literal is illegal in C++. (But my compiler still allows it...)

Comment: The fifth one should be legal in c++11, which would also give you constexpr, which should let you make all five equivalent with some modification.  (disclaimer - my c++11 experience is not practical as I am not yet able to move production code to anything with good c++11 support)

Comment: @KennyOstrom: No, the fifth isn't legal in C++11. An initialiser list isn't convertible to a pointer, which is just as well since it doesn't persist after the object has been initialised.

Comment: Let [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org) be your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declarations are not exactly equivalent: the first, third and fourth declarations make writable copies of string literals, while the second one does not make a copy. As the result, it is legal to make an assignment like this

```
cString1[0] = 'S'; // cString3 and cString4 would work as well
```

while trying to do the same with `cString2` triggers undefined behavior.

Declarations number three and four are identical, except that the number three lets the compiler figure out the size of the array, while the number four specifies it explicitly. You could rewrite the first declaration like this

```
char cString1a[7]="string";
```

to follow the same pattern.

Although `"string"` can be rewritten as `{'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}` in array declarations, it is not legal in the context of initializing a pointer. That is why the last declaration does not work.

However, in c99 you can rewrite it with a *compound literal* to make it work ([demo](http://ideone.com/pHSq9P)):

```
char * cString5 = (char[]){'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "writable copies of string literals?"  Also, I was not aware that cString2[0]='S' would give undefined behavior. I thought this was just shorthand for a pointer arithmetic operation, which is OK. Is that only for C?

Comment: It is shorthand for pointer arithmetic and dereferencing, the trouble is that your pointer to non-const actually points to a non-modifiable const literal.

Comment: @David `cString2[0]='S'` is undefined behavior because the pointer points to memory of a string literal, which is not modifiable (e.g. the standard lets compilers place string literals in read-only memory). In C++ `cString2` assignment wouldn't compile at all - you'd need to write `const char * cString2 = "string"`, which would also prohibit assignments to individual characters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The Gnu compiler only gives a deprecation warning.

Comment: @Deduplicator Interesting - I thought it was an error. I guess this is because I use `-Werror` option.

Comment: Well, I might not use `-Werror`, but I handle any warnings as breaking the build anyway.

Answer (score 2):

They're (clearly) not equivalent.
`"string"` is a static array of chars that contains the chars`'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'`.  However, `{stuff}` is an *initializer list*.  It is a static array of elements used to initialize the left hand side.  An array decays to a pointer, but an initializer list does not, since it is not an array.  Even more confusing, there's a special case in C and C++ that a `char[]` can be initialized from a string literal, even though normally initializing an array by "copy" like this is illegal.

```
char cString1[]="string"; //special case for string literal array copy

char * cString2 = "string"; //array decays to pointer

char cString3[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g', '\0'}; //constructing array from list

char cString4[7] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}; //constructing array from list

char * cString5 = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}; //list DOES NOT decay to pointer.

char cString7[7] = "string"; //also special case for string literal array copy
```

As noted by dasblinkenlight, two of these are pointers to static data, whereas three of these are local arrays that are initialized by copying from static data.  They're similar, but not the same.

Comment: And when you say "special case for string literal array copy"; what do you mean by copy? The "=" sign?

Comment: @David: Yes, normally arrays cannot be copy assigned nor copy initialized.  A `char[]` array from a string literal is special though.

Answer (score 1):

> `"string"` and `{'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}` are equivalent

As the initialiser of a character array, yes. In other contexts, no.

> the first four declarations below all compile and seem to do the same thing.

No they don't; three of them declare arrays, while two (try to) declare pointers.

> But then why doesn't the fifth declaration compile?

Because it tries to initialise a pointer with something unsuitable for initialising a pointer.

> what exactly is going on in the four correct and the one incorrect cstring declaration?

The first declares a local array, initialised by copying the string literal (including its terminator) into it. The size is inferred from the literal.

The second declares a local pointer, initialised to point to a string literal. The literal itself is a static array of `const char`. A modern compiler shouldn't accept this, since the literal is `const` but the pointer is not. Older versions of the language accepted this dodgy conversion for compatibility with ancient code.

The third declares a local array, initialised from a list. The size is inferred from the list. The result is the same as the first.

The fourth is the same as the third, but specifies the size explicitly.

The fifth is invalid; a pointer has to point to an object (or be null), and an initialiser list is not an object.

In C++, it's usually more convenient to use `std::string` to represent strings, rather than messing around with low-level arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`char cString1[]="string";` declares an array of `char` of an unspecified size (calculated by compiler) and initializes it with an const array of 7 `char` (including the `'\0'` terminator)

`char * cString2 = "string";' declares a pointer to`char`and initializes it with a const array of 7`char`(including the`'\0'` terminator)

`char cString3[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g', '\0'};` is like the first one, except in this case the initializing array is explicitly defined char-by-char, including the terminator. N.B. if you omit the terminator in this code the string will be unterminated and will likely cause your program to access invalid memory (for instance when trying to print that string)

`char cString4[7] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};` is like the previous one except you define the size of your array. If you have more (or fewer!) elements in the initializing array than you specified - compiler won't be happy about that

`char * cString5 = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};` is illegal because you are declaring a pointer to `char` but initializing it with an array of `char`

Answer (score 0):

cString1 is a string array[] of 1 object[0]

cString2 is a string containing 6 characters

cString3 is a string array[] of 7 objects[7]

cString4 is a string array[7] of 7 object[7]

cString5 is a string that you try to declare into 7 objects