# Difference between char[] and int[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

So recently, I  watched a video where it said that when I defined an array of integers for example

```cpp
int my_array[] = {1,2,3};
```

and I printed my_array `cout << my_array;` then I would get the address of the first integer in memory, but when we define an array of characters like

```cpp
char my_string[] = "Hello";
```

then when I try to print my_string `cout << my_string` it returns `Hello`, **similarly** with pointers when we define a pointer to characters

```cpp
char mystring[] = "HELLO";
char *my = mystring;
cout << my << endl;//HELLO
```

and we try to print the pointer variable it returns the string.

Now I've read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873891/the-difference-between-char-and-int) and I read that the string takes the memory address with him. But I still can't figure out why they are not the same and why an array of chars prints the string literal and the int array prints the address of the first one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `char *my = mystring;` -> `char *my = my_string;`? `why an array of chars returns the string literal` you mean that doing `cout << mystring` it __prints__ the string?

Comment: sorry fixed the typo

Comment: They both return the address of the first one. That's how strings are represented in C: as a pointer to a sequence of characters terminated by a '\0' character. (When converted to a pointer at least; int[] will decompose to int* but is initially different.)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry, wrote a wrong thing, see my edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Comment: the difference is that char arrays are treated special in C, a string is an array of characters with an ending \0 value, that is why when you print a string the function knows when to stop.

Comment: @flowit No it does not entirely, my question is about why when I print the array name it does not return the address of the first char and im only referring to a pointer as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why an array of chars returns the string literal and the int array returns the address of the first one.

I assume the word "returns" is meant to "print".

Because the [non-member `std::ostream::operator<<(ostream&, const char *)` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) iterates over the memory the `char*` pointer points to and prints the content of it, while there is no `std::ostream::operator<<(int*)` overload, so `int*` is casted to `const void*` and [`std::ostream::operator<<(const void*)` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is used to print the value, and that function prints the value of the pointer.

You can still print the value of the pointer to string by casting it manually:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(my_string) << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, so in the end the only reason the string is printed is because of the i/o stream overload?

Comment: Well, yes, because it's specified to act that way.

Answer (score 4):

This is a hangover from C and the fact that the standard library has to support C style strings (which are `char*` null terminated). To this end `std::cout` has an overload for `const char*` which treats it as a C style string and prints up to a null termiator.

Printing the address is the normal behavior for a pointer being passed to `std::cout` (hence your `int` pointer memory location printout).

Answer (score 3):

> my_array would contain the address of the first integer in memory,

No. `my_array` would contain the three integers in memory.

> if i do cout << myarray << endl then that would print the address of the first item in memory

Yes. That is how character streams are specified to behave. When you insert a pointer, the address will be printed. Except in the case you insert a pointer to char which is treated differently.

> and how is it treated differently?

As per documentation, the pointed character, and its siblings will be printed until the null teminator character is reached.

Comment: if i do `cout << myarray << endl` then that would print the address of the first item in memory

Comment: Oh ok thank you, and how is it treated differently?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `my_array` is an `int[3]`, and mystring is a `char[6]`.

The reason the `cout << my_string;` prints a string is because these conversions get applied
`char[6] -> char const *`, and the ostream `operator<<` knows to treat a `char const *` as a `string`.

For the `cout << my_array`, the conversion would be `int[3] -> int * -> void const *`. The ostream `operator<<` on a `void const *` simply prints the address.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration of an array of characters

```
char my_string[] = "Hello";
```

is equivalent to the following declaration

```
char my_string[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

That is the elements of the array are initialized by the characters of the string literal including its terminating zero.

Used in expressions arrays with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

For example if you are using the sizeof operator then an object of an array type is not converted to pointer to its first element. This one of rare exception.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    char my_string[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << "sizeof( my_array ) = " << sizeof( my_array ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof( my_string ) = " << sizeof( my_string ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( my_array ) = 12
sizeof( my_string ) = 6
```

But for example when an object of an array type is used as an operand of the operator * then it is converted to pointer to its first element.

Here is another demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    char my_string[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << "*my_array = " << *my_array << '\n';
    std::cout << "*my_string = " << *my_string << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
*my_array = 1
*my_string = H
```

In the C++ Standard there is defined the overloaded `operator <<` to output strings (sequence of characters terminated by the zero character) pointed to by a pointer to char.

So if you will write

```
std::cout << my_string << '\n';
```

then in the call of this operator << the character array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and the pointed string is outputted.

For integer arrays the operator << is defined such a way that it just outputs the address of the array that is the address of its first element.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    char my_string[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << my_array << '\n';
    std::cout << my_string << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
0x7ffdcfe094e4
Hello
```

If you want that for a character array there would be selected the overloaded operator << that outputs the address of the array then you should cast the array (that is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element) to the type `void *`.

Here is one more demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    char my_string[] = "Hello";

    std::cout << my_array << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<void *>( my_string ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
0x7ffef7ac0104
0x7ffef7ac0112
```